# OpenGL obj file not rendering right in JOGL

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, jogl, wavefront

I am building a simple **Wavefront Obj file loader** and renderer in Java, using JOGL. However, whenever I am loading a simple bunny test mesh, it's rendering in a glitchy fashion, and I have no idea what could be causing it. I am just using geometry vertices and normals, no textures or materials.

[image: the experienced glitch]

[image: another angle of that glitch]

The following is the GL initialization code from the `init()` method:

```
gl.setSwapInterval(1);
gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);        
gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
gl.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LESS);
gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_CULL_FACE);
gl.glCullFace(GL2.GL_BACK);
gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH);
gl.glClearDepth(1.0d);
```

And this is the method that I'm using to render the model (fixed pipeline, for now):

```
 gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES);
    for(Face face : master.faces) {
        for(int i = 0; i < face.points.length; i++) {
            gl.glNormal3f(face.normals[i].x, face.normals[i].y, face.normals[i].z);             
            gl.glVertex3f(face.points[i].x, face.points[i].y, face.points[i].z);
        }
    }
    gl.glEnd();
```

Where `master` is the main "group" that contains *all* the faces and vertices. I've checked - everything goes into the master group, and glNormal3f and glVertex3f get called for every needed vertex in every triangle.

Can anyone tell what could be causing those glitches?

### Edit 1:

Here is the code I'm using to set the projection and modelview matrices up:

```
float aspect = (float) width / (float) height;

gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();

glu.gluPerspective(60.0f, aspect, 0.01f, 100.0f);
glu.gluLookAt(2.0f, 1.0f, 1.5f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

Comment: First, are you sure all your faces defined in the obj file are triangles (Wavefront obj supports arbitrary face sizes)?

Comment: @pwny yes, I'm sure of that! For debugging purposes I only allow triangular faces to be defined

Comment: Where's your projection and modelview matrix setup code?  Context creation?

Comment: genpfault: I've updated the question; As for the context creation, no special code is used for that; JOGL handles the basics automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seemed like this was being caused by a silly little bug in my object loader.
When parsing my input vertices, it would chomp the first character of all the x coordinates of the geometry vertices. This didn't affect the positive values, since they were all normalized and `0.43 = .43`, but it messed up all negative values causing them to be interpreted as positive.

It took me a while to figure that out, but I eventually found it and it just goes to show that the tiniest errors can be incredibly tricky to track down.

Answer (score 1):

try removing
gl.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LESS);
gl.glClearDepth(1.0d);

Comment: That didn't help, it's still rendering badly

Comment: gl.glCullFace(GL2.GL_FRONT);?

Comment: Well, that makes it look a bit better, but it's still only rendering half of the mesh, and some of the artifacts are still there.

Comment: may be normal vectors are broken? try to open with Blender and fix normals

Comment: i see that bunny is a standard model... but may be the source is wrong... also try to disable culling